# making a call and press a number while in a call programmatically?

Tags: android

I have to develop a android application that makes calls automatic. It is an easy part. Hard part is I have to follow the instructions if the receiver is a answering machine or customer care service. how can I press the numbers according to the instructions? for a example "press number 1 for the English language". then this app should be able to press number 1.

is this possible? any references would be appreciated. thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control other apps. So your app can't press number 1.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. what if we implement this as a service?

Comment: `Service` will not help. It's just security rule which you can't avoid.